# Elasticsearch sort data upon all buckets

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I am trying to make an es sort but I am struggling.

The base story of my data is that I have for example product definition which can consist of various products. (We call them abstract and concrete).

Let's say I have product A that is abstract it can consist of product B,C,D (called concretes).

I also for example have product E that can have F as a concrete and so on.

I want to aggregate the products by their abstract (to only show 1 of each concrete) and then sort all concretes based on some criteria.

I have written the following that doesn't work as expected.

```
 "aggs": {
"category:58": {
  "aggs": {
    "products": {
      "aggs": {
        "abstract": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "criteria1": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              },
              {
                "_score": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              },
              {
                "criteria3": {
                  "missing": "_last",
                  "order": "asc",
                  "unmapped_type": "integer"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "terms": {
        "field": "abstract_id",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "term": {
      "categories.id": {
        "value": "58"
      }
    }
  }
}
},
```

If I got it correctly this will create 10 buckets and each bucket will have one product, and then my sort sorts a single product, where I should be sorting the entire result. The question is where do I place my sort that is currently in aggs->abstract.
If I remove the grouping by abstract_id and change it to something that is unique then the sorting does work, but then for one abstract product I can get all concretes displayed which I don't want to be the case.

I saw that I can't sort on terms so I'm kinda clueless now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using multiple aggregations and then doing a bucket sort.
The query I ended up with looks like this

```
          "aggs": {
        "abstract": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        },
        "criteria3": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "custom_filed_foo_bar"
          }
        },
        "criteria1": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "boosted_value"
          }
        },
        "criteria2": {
          "max": {
            "script":{
              "source": "_score"
            }
          }
        },
        "sorting": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "criteria1": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              },
                                {
                "criteria2": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              },
                                {
                "criteria3": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
```

I don't know if it's the correct approach but seems to be working